# Rename and move multiple Images

Tags: bash, shell

I want to move and rename some jpg images. They are in 13 different folders and are named differently. I tried to write a short script that does the work for me. Unfortunately the second for loop does not work. The line echo $file echos me "IMAGES" instead of the image names.

```
#!/bin/sh

path="/Users/fflach/Desktop/Training/Kindernahrung"
k=0

for i in {1..13} ;
    do
        currentPath="$path $i 1,30 m"
        IMAGES="$currentPath/*.jpg"
        for file in IMAGES ;
            do
                k=k+1
                moveFile="$currentPath/$file"
                echo $file
                destination="/Users/fflach/Desktop/Training/New/$k.jpg"
                mv $moveFile $destination
            done
    done
```

How can I change the second loop so that it loops over all .jpg named images?

Comment: Try `for file in $IMAGES ;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as $currentPath and $destination variables contain spaces must be between double quotes to avoid splitting.

to increment k : `typeset -i k` and `k=k+1` or use arithmetic `((k=k+1))`

```
#!/bin/sh

path="/Users/fflach/Desktop/Training/Kindernahrung"
typeset -i k=0

for i in {1..13} ;
do
    currentPath="$path $i 1,30 m"
    for file in "$currentPath"/*.jpg ;
    do
        k=k+1
        moveFile=$file
        echo "$file"
        destination="/Users/fflach/Desktop/Training/New/$k.jpg"
        mv "$moveFile" "$destination"
    done
done
```